# drupal views dynamic filter

Tags: drupal, dynamic, filter, view

I have a Drupal website where I post tournament results.
I have created a content-type where i write the result for 1 person in the tournament. So the fields are like: Date of tournament, player name, final position.
If 10 people played in the tournament, I create this content for each player.

Now, I would like to create a table with views, to list all the players in the tournament, and the various info, like player name/final position. I can do that pretty easy by adding the fields and sorting criteria in views. But my problem is, what I should do next time we have a tournament. I would like to just use the same view settings, but without having to clone the previous view, just to change the date filter-criteria.
So, I need the user to be able to view tournament page, and then see the results for that specific tournament. Then if the user go to see a different page from another tournament, then only those results will show up.
And I wish to do it in a clean way, where I don't have to clone the view and just change date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a **view** with a **contextual filter**. The contextual filter will handle a **taxonomy** or **node reference** so that you can use only 1 dynamic view. But in order to make this work, you might want to adjust your content type a little so that it's easier for your view to filter them:

Your current content type has all the information of a contestant/player (Date of tournament, player name, final position), so it would be better to name that content type Contestant.
Then create a new taxonomy or content type: Tournament which will handle the information of a Tournament. Keeping these separated is a better approach.

So let's say you have a taxonomy: Tournament taxonomy with all your tournaments set up. Then you can add this as a term reference field in your content type: Contestant.
(Add a new **term reference** field: "Tournament" with widget: **select list**.)

---

Create your **view**:

- **Filter criteria** -> Content:Type (=Contestant)
- **Page settings** -> Path: `/tournaments/%`
- **Contextual filter** -> Content: Has taxonomy term ID
- **Override title** -> `%1`

---

For each **taxonomy term** (Tournament) you have this view now has a page. So when for example you go to `http://yourdrupal/tournaments/1` it will filter your view only for that tournament.

I attached an image so that you can see how I configurated my view

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that well written answer. It did exactly what I was looking for, and also got me closer to fully understand how contextual filters works. I still find it a bit tricky, but your post did explain it very well!