# Get content Id (nid) from path on views block

Tags: drupal-7, view, drupal-contextual-filters

I just can't seem to wrap my head around Drupal relationships. I have been reading and watching tutorials, but as soon as I try to get my own project done - I fail. I think it's very basic, so I would love to understand it. Maybe someone here can help me understand how it works :)

On my drupal site, I want to keep track of some private game tournaments.
I have created a content type called contestant, which has fields like: Tournament date, Player name, Final Position. I can then create a view that list the information from one tournament. I used the help I got from this thread: [drupal views dynamic filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344730/drupal-views-dynamic-filter)

I would like to have the view described above as a block. And then place that block-view on a "tournament description" page. I could do this, by simply creating a new block each time, and then manually place it on the page it should be shown (structure-->Blocks-->configure), but that is not an elegant way to do it. I am pretty sure this is where Relationships should be used. But I fail to understand how to create this relationship, so that the specific block view, that matches the specific tournament description page will be displayed together.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Content:Nid** as a **Contextual filter**.

- WHEN the Filter value is not in the URL >>
- Provide default value
- Content ID from URL

[image]